# Failure when trying to create a pdf document in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, laravel-5, pdf-generation

I have a site using Laravel 5.0.35 that I have inherited that has two functions, active and inactive, that reads a database of people and looks at the status field to produce a PDF document.

The active function works but the inactive does not.  It throws the following error:

> FileNotFoundException in File.php line 41:
>   The file ".../laravel/app/PDFs/individual/inactive-participants.1544562943.pdf" does not exist
>   in File.php line 41
>
> at File->__construct('.../laravel/app/PDFs/individual/inactive-participants.1544562943.pdf') in BinaryFileResponse.php line 91
>
> at BinaryFileResponse->setFile('.../laravel/app/PDFs/individual/inactive-participants.1544562943.pdf', 'attachment', false, true) in BinaryFileResponse.php line 50
>
> at BinaryFileResponse->__construct('.../laravel/app/PDFs/individual/inactive-participants.1544562943.pdf', '200', array(), true, 'attachment') in -ResponseFactory.php line 129
>
> at ResponseFactory->download('.../laravel/app/PDFs/individual/inactive-participants.1544562943.pdf') in ReportsController.php line 200

The function looks like this:

```
public function gInctve(Request $request)
{
    $tokenName = $request->get('tokenName');
    Cookie::queue($tokenName, $tokenName, 1, null, null, false, false);

    $fullPaths = [];
    $time = time();

    People::with('upple', 'plans.share')
        ->with(['plans' => function($query) {
            $query->join('shares', 'plans.share_id', '=', 'shares.id')- 
 >orderBy('shares.year', 'asc');
        }])
        ->has('plans')
        ->orderBy('Peoples.People_no', 'asc')
        ->where('Peoples.vesting_percentage', '>', 0)
        ->chunk(200, function($Peoples) use(&$fullPaths, $time){
            foreach ($Peoples as $People) {
                if (is_null($People->upple)) continue;

                if ($People->upple->STATUS == 1 or  $People->plans- 
>sum('shares') <=0) continue;

                $fileName = (trim($People->ssn) . '.' . $time . '.pdf');

                $this->PeopleReportGenerator->generate($People, $fileName);

                $fullPaths[] = config('esop.individual_statements_dir') . 
$fileName;
            }
        });

    $mergedPdfFullPath = config('esop.individual_statements_dir') . 
'inactive-participants.' . $time . '.pdf';

    passthru('cpdf ' . implode(' ', $fullPaths) . ' -o ' . 
$mergedPdfFullPath);

    return response()->download($mergedPdfFullPath);
}
```

If I change `if ($People->upple->STATUS == 1` to match the active function, `if ($People->upple->STATUS != 1` it works as the active function should.  I have tried changing the line to be `===` and `!= 3`  (The status field is either 1 or 3).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. The error says _The file ".../laravel/app/PDFs/individual/inactive-participants.1544562943.pdf" does not exist _ Does it really exist? You can check that the file exists before passing it to `generate`, if it doesn't exist, then `continue`. It will remove the exception. But is it what you expect?

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I will give that a try and see what it shows.  The file does not exist.  It should create the file in the folder labeled individual and then give the option to save a copy through the browser.  It is strange that it works when the STATUS is changed.  Thank you again.

Comment: The file never gets created. I can not see it in the individual folder.

Comment: Oops, my previous comment was wrong, I thought that the error was earlier in the code. So, is individual created, what does `$fullPaths` contain? Is the call to `cpdf` failing?

Comment: I am not sure which part is failing as the stack trace is confusing to me as it doesnt seem to point to a clear issue.  Records are pulled from a database and then loop pulls out the records that are no longer active using the foreach.  The if statement that seems to be broken should remove entries that are still active.   Is there any code I can add to see what it pulls before it crashes or to clarify what it is crashing on?